# how to declare array using string array from resource?

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-arrayadapter

I have created a string array in the resource directory with three item value. Then tried to put the array in the string x . It doesn't show any error but crashes.

```
 String x[]= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.z_array);
    String y[]={"1","2","3"};
enter code here
```

The string array code is as follow-

```
<string-array name="z_array">
<item>a</item>
<item>b</item>
<item>c</item>
```

Instead of declaring x[] like above, if i use

```
     String x[]= {"a","b","c"};
```

It works fine.

This is my custom adapter code-

```
   public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           String[] objects,String[] objects2){

        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_view, parent, false);

        TextView nameV= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.uuuu);

        nameV.setText(x[position]);

        TextView authorNameV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vvvv);
        authorNameV.setText(y[position]);

        switch (position) {
            default:
                break;
        }

        return view ;
    }

}
```

My question is how to declare array using  string array from resource?

Logcat

```
    02-25 03:45:34.851 5845-5845/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
02-25 03:45:34.851 5845-5845/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
02-25 03:45:40.011 5857-5857/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
02-25 03:45:40.011 5857-5857/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
02-25 03:45:40.741 5870-5870/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
02-25 03:45:40.741 5870-5870/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
02-25 03:45:40.931 5881-5881/? E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories
02-25 03:45:40.931 5881-5881/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories, PID: 5881
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories/maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
                                                     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:542)
                                                     at maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:35)
                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1064)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-25 03:45:41.311 5898-5898/? E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories
02-25 03:45:41.311 5898-5898/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories, PID: 5898
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories/maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
                                                     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:542)
                                                     at maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:35)
                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1064)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-25 03:45:41.451 5910-5910/? E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories
02-25 03:45:41.451 5910-5910/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories, PID: 5910
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories/maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
                                                     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:542)
                                                     at maruf.infinity.story.englishshortstories.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:35)
                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1064)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where exactly are you using this? getResources().getStringArray(R.array.z_array); Also, could you post your stack trace?

Comment: I am using the custom adapter for a listview. I have got this in the verbose

>>||02-25 03:36:21.581 2032-2084/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor W/BstCommandProcessor-Application: in sendHttpRequest, requestType is of CRASH_APP type but one of the requiredInfo is NULL, crashedApp = com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor.BstCrashedAppInfo@4e822b74 ||<<

Comment: hi @Mohammad, i was talking about this piece of code ``getResources().getStringArray(R.array.z_array);``

Comment: what is stack , I am a juvenile learner in android studio. Would you please say what more detail  is needed?

Comment: stack trace is where you see all messages yield by Android, you can see the crash report in the logcat tab in Android Studio

Comment: okay, please take a look at the TextView nameV. there i have used that piece of code.

Comment: You're calling `getResources()` outside of a class method in `MainActivity`. You can't do that there, as the `Activity`'s `Context` will get yet be attached. Move that call into a method; e.g., `onCreate()`.

Comment: @MikeM. certainly it worked :) I have got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codes about getting array from resources are ok . For making sure about your `x[]` values , you can print them on `logcat`

```
for (String name : x) {
        Log.d(name);
    }
```

There is a big but , I suppose you created your adapter inside MainActivity as an inner class right ?

If No : your x[] and y[] are null .
If yes : show me how to instansiate your adapter and set it to your list view .